# probability of left handedness

Tags: distributions

13 random people were chosen from the US population . 12 were found to be left handed, (none ambidextrous).  Assume the incidence of left handedness in the US is 13%, and does not change with gender or race or sexual orientation or IQ.

What were the chances of this occurring?

Comment: This looks like homework. Please read https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the self-study tag if it is.

Comment: _Very small:_ If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=13, p=0.13),$ then $P(X=12) = {13\choose 12}(.13)^{12}(1-.13),$ according to @LorenzoPacchiardi (+1). Using binomial PDF `dbinom` in R with code `dbinom(12, 13, .13)`, we get $2.635013e-10,$ but $13(.13)^{12}(1-.13)$ is not difficult to evaluate on a calculator.

Comment: @DrT Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question. Once you do so, you'll be able to edit your question without submitting it for review. Also, remarks on reviews are not the place to ask for clarification about an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Specifically, say $p=0.13$. Then, each person in your sample has probability $p$ of being left handed, and $1-p$ of not being so.

Say $k=12,\ n=13$. Then, the probability of $k$ people out of $n$ being left handed is $ p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \binom {n}{k} $, where $\binom {n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $ .

Quoting Wikipedia:

> The formula can be understood as follows: $k$ successes occur with probability $p^k$ and $n − k$ failures occur with probability $(1 − p)^{n − k}$. However, the $k$ successes can occur anywhere among the $n$ trials, and there are ${\binom {n}{k}}$ different ways of distributing $k$ successes in a sequence of $n$ trials.